# has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-xhr-logon is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to consume external restful web service in sap ui5. When I consume the same in fiori launchpad it throws below error in cosole and no data comes in the tile app. How can I over come with that? I have checked many blogs relted to that but didn't get any help from that.

Error : 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/ijyy2' from origin 'url2' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-xhr-logon is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Note : url2= https://sapmobile.mycompanyname.com is nothing but our fiori 
launchpad url.

Comment: Your client-side code is sending a `x-xhr-logon` request header, but the remote endpoint is currently not saying that this is one of the allowed headers. You either need to make your code stop sending that request header, or the receiving end must respond with an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header, that lists this `x-xhr-logon` as an allowed one. (Those are the two options in theory; which is the “correct” one for your situation, you’ll have to figure out - we don’t know if that header is necessary/serves any purpose.)

Comment: I have checked below blog but could not specify where to write first point of code in server. https://blogs.sap.com/2017/10/01/cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-issue-resolved/

Comment: Same issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2402

Answer (score 4):

This is a known Fiori Launchpad problem. There is a file `abap.js` which overrides the default `send` method of `XMLHttpRequest`.

If you add the external API as a new destination in the SAP Cloud Platform (or use a Web Dispatcher in an on-premise environment) then there will be no more CORS calls and thus no more CORS problems.

If you want a pure JavaScript solution you can restore the original implementation with two functions. Add these to your controller.

Call the following immediately before accessing your external API

```
_overrideRequestPrototype: function () {
    if (!XMLHttpRequest._SAP_ENHANCED) {
        return;
    }
    this.__send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (oBody) {
        let oChannel = {};
        this._checkEventSubscriptions();
        try {
            oChannel = this._channel;
            this._saveParams(oBody);
            this._send(oBody);
            if (oChannel) {
                oChannel.sent();
            }
        } catch (oError) {
            if (oChannel) {
                oChannel["catch"](oError);
            } else {
                throw oError;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

After the call, restore the SAP code with the following function:

```
_restoreRequestPrototype: function () {
    if (!XMLHttpRequest._SAP_ENHANCED) {
        return;
    }
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = this.__send;
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc,    Thanks for your reply. I am getting expected token build time error. My ajx call is there in the oninit function. Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Seems like a syntax error when you copied the code.

Comment: Do you want me to share the code? Please let me know.

Comment: Yes, please share your code. Please use something like gist.github.com

Comment: Hi MArc.. you can find my code(Ztabledemo.zip) in this url: https://github.com/rkmishra2703/RK-

Comment: Yeah Marc ..I have removed that then you can suggest the right place to put the code as I said was not able to fit suggested code in my application code.

Comment: Hi Marc did you get a chnace to check where should I put code shared by you.

Comment: Marc, I tried and it worked. Really very thankful to you. Will this be fail in future release or so. Can I rely on this solution

Comment: Well I can't promise anything, but it should be pretty reliable.

Comment: I have raised this to SAP, and SAP has agreed that this is a bug. I am expecting the resolution anytime now.